# Question on Rudin Theorem 3.31 Proof

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

On page 65, we have:

> $e-s_n = \frac{1}{(n+1)!}+\frac{1}{(n+2)!}+\frac{1}{(n+3)!}+\dots < \frac{1}{(n+1)!}(1 + \frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}+\dots)=\frac{1}{n!n}$

Given $s_n = \sum_{k=0}^{n}{\frac{1}{k!}}$.

What I don't understand is, where does $\frac{1}{n!n}$ come from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It comes from computing the sum of a geometric series:\begin{align}1+\frac1{n+1}+\frac1{(n+1)^2}+\cdots&=\frac1{1-1/(n+1)}\\&=\frac{n+1}n.\end{align}So,$$\frac1{(n+1)!}\left(1+\frac1{n+1}+\frac1{(n+1)^2}+\cdots\right)=\frac{n+1}{(n+1)!n}=\frac1{n!n}.$$

Answer (score 2):

Note that since for $ |a| < 1$ (Geometric series formula)
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}a^i = \frac{1}{1-a},
$$
choosing $a := \frac{1}{n+1}$, on the right hand side it follows that
$$
\frac{1}{(n+1)!}\left(\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{1}{n+1}\right)^i\right) = \frac{1}{(n+1)!}\left(\frac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{n+1}}\right) = \frac{1}{n!n}
$$